# CKEDITOR innerHTML not working on IMG Tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a custom plugin.  It is an image loader.  It worked on CKEditor before I upgraded to the latest version as of yesterday (downloaded fresh and installed with Office2003 skin).

My Plugin calls the editor, i see it in the debugger

```
open:   function(editor) {
    this._editor = editor;
    this._show();
    this._getFileList();
},
```

It gets its files, i click on a file, it does its thing, and then the function is called to bring it back to the CKEditors Textarea Div.

```
    var imagetag = "<img src=\"" + src + "\" alt=\"" + alt + "\" height=\"" + height + "\" width=\"" + width + "\" style=\"" + style + "\">";
    this._editor.insertHtml("SOME TEST TEXT");
    this._editor.insertHtml(imagetag);
```

The imagetag does its thing, and i can see that in the debugger

```
<img src="http://localhost/3.3/data/system/assets/groups/thumbs/67b1e878ebb463e13bad7f7e31a43ecb-thumb.jpeg" alt="File" height="96" width="145" style="border:0px;margin:0px;">
```

I test the link in the browser

```
http://localhost/3.3/data/system/assets/groups/thumbs/67b1e878ebb463e13bad7f7e31a43ecb-thumb.jpeg
```

And i can see the file.  But its not being appended to the CKEditor window. Although I do see the text SOME TEST TEXT which is appended so i know that the innerHTML is working, it is no longer displaying the image in the window relative to the img tag.

If i put some text around the img like

```
SOME<img>TEXT
```

it outputs

```
SOMETEXT
```

Why is the Editor Textarea no longer displaying my image after an upgrade of CK.

Comment: When you switch to Source mode and type `SOME<img>TEXT`, then switch back to WYSIWYG mode, you get `SOMETEXT`. Now, if you switch to Source mode again you see `<p>SOME<img />TEXT</p>`, right?

Comment: i check the code in the debugger and i see <p>SOMETEXT</p> i do not see any html.  That is under `<body contenteditable=true>` in the CKEDitor section of the code. So no `<img>` at all

Comment: I have cut my load code to the very very basic, my config file to just the toolbar layout, loaded very minimal items, run through the plugin and echoed to the console, and i see the html go into the CKEDITOR.innerHTML(), ive output text along with it, ive tried other tags.its only allow plain text through.  Any settings i might need to turn on.

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules, seems its turned off and you need to allow content.  The things they dont advise you of. So you either set it to true, and turn off the filter, or have to write a script of allowable items.  Pain in the ass, but i see the value.